# Webpack watch doesn't regenerate styles on Windows

Tags: webpack, stylus

Using `webpack --watch`, `extract-text-webpack-plugin` and `stylus-loader`, webpack doesn't regenerate styles on Windows 8.1, unless you change something in the main referenced `.styl` file (in this case `styles.styl` as seen below).

On OS X and Linux it doesn't matter which `.styl` file I change, it regenerates anyway, as intended (?).

**EDIT:** Upon further investigation it seems that it does regenerate on Windows even when changing other files, but **very** seldom (like once every minute or so) and seemingly completely at random.

It's setup like this:

**app.js** (main entry point)

```
'use strict';

// Contains all other stylus imports
import 'assets/css/styles.styl';

// Other code...
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';

module.exports = {
  // ...
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')
    },
    {
      test: /\.styl$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!stylus-loader?paths=src')
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('css/styles.css', { allChunks: true })
  ]
};
```

**styles.styl**

```
@require "config/*";

@import "layout/*";
@import "general/*";
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <!-- Other stuff -->
  </head>
  <!-- Even more stuff -->
</html>
```

Comment: This sounds like a file system problem.  Perhaps you have an editor open with the .styl file?  No reason I can think of that webpack wouldn't immediately write the changes upon re-compilation.

Comment: @4m1r No, nothing like that. I suppose the fault may lie with `stylus-loader` as well.

Comment: ya, perhaps open an issue with them. @shama is helpful.

Comment: i can't get it work too. https://github.com/crapthings/postcss-test